# Определить, в объекте массив объектов или один объект

Tags: php, simplexml

Есть объекты со следующим содержимым:

С массивом объектов:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Предложение] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
                ( [Ид] => id )
            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                ( [Ид] => id )
         )
)
```

И с одним объектом:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Предложение] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        ()
)
```

Как определить каждый из них?

Проверки на `is_array()`,  `is_object` и `isset( $obj -> Ид )` не работают.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полагаю, в вашем случае вы можете использовать метод [`count`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/simplexmlelement.count.php) (не тот `count`, что считает элементы в массиве).

Хотя на самом деле, вы как минимум можете итерироваться и по одному объекту и по массиву одним и тем же кодом:

```
$s = '<rt>
    <el>1</el>
</rt>';

$x = simplexml_load_string($s);
foreach ($x->el as $el) {
    var_dump($el);
}

$s = '<rt>
    <el>2</el>
    <el>3</el>
    <el>4</el>
</rt>';

$x = simplexml_load_string($s);
foreach ($x->el as $el) {
    var_dump($el);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array=array
(
    "Предложение" => array(
            "0" => 
                array( "Ид" => "id" ),
            "1" => array( "Ид" => "id" )
         )
);




$arr2=array(
    "Предложение" => array()
);

function get_lvl(array $array) {
    $max_lvl = 1;

    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $lvl= get_lvl($value) + 1;

            if ($lvl> $max_lvl) {
                $max_lvl = $lvl;
            }
        }
    }

    return $max_lvl;
}

if(get_lvl($array)>"1"){
echo "массив имеет вложенность".get_lvl($array);
}
```